# How can I get the value of lower timeframe value and show it in a higher timeframe (Pinescript - Version 5)

Tags: pine-script

Currently, I'm writing an indicator showing the buy/sell volume. My point is that I can get the buy and sell volume by the candle parts (OHLC) from lower timeframe. From it, I will calculate the sum value of these candles in a higher timeframe (eg: sum of 96 volume value of M15 timeframe, show it in D1 timeframe)

Because it is volume, and my calculations included higher numbers minus lower numbers, so all the results supposed to be positive (>=0), but when I look back at the chart, some values are below 0

Below is my code, and I will explain each part of it, pretty simple logic.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Accumulate', overlay=false)

t = time_close("15", "0000-0001")

count = ta.barssince(t)+1

count:=nz(count)
if count<=0
    count:=1
```

I make "t" as a condition to count the number of m15 bars from the start to the end of a day, this will be used in the sum function.

---

```
red_sell = if request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close < open)
    math.sum((open-close)/(high-low)*volume, count)

red_buy = if request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close < open)
    math.sum((high-open+close-low)/(high-low)*volume, count)

green_sell = if request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close > open)
    math.sum((high-close+open-low)/(high-low)*volume, count)

green_buy = if request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close > open)
    math.sum((close-open)/(high-low)*volume, count)
```

I find the sell & buy volume from both red & green candles, then count the sum of them with the barssince function that I mentioned above.

---

I found that "sell volume from red candle" and "buy volume from green candle" are usually got below 0 (negative values). So now I am confusing whether my code was wrong somewhere, or these values should be actually below 0
[image: buy volume of green candles below 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting data from the lower timeframes with the `request.security()` is not supported.

Instead, you should use the newly introduced `request.security_lower_tf()` function.

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("`request.security_lower_tf()` Example", overlay = true)

// If the current chart timeframe is set to 120 minutes, then the `arrayClose` array will contain two 'close' values from the 60 minute timeframe for each bar.
arrClose = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "60", close)

if bar_index == last_bar_index - 1
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(arrClose))
```